# servlet mapping and servlet name web.xml

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

i ve been given a project to modify and when i try to edit something i got this ERROR

```
484 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/].[apirestwebservice]] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet apirestwebservice threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when i searched for the **apirestwebservice** i found it in the xml file as a servlet

```
<servlet-name>apirestwebservice</servlet-name>

<servlet> 
   <servlet-name>siterefServlet</servlet-name> 
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-clas‌​s> 
   <init-param> 
     <param-name>CoLo</param-name> 
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config/spring-mvc-context.xml</param-value> 
   </init-param> 
   <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>
```

So what i thought is i am just going to find the apirestwebservice.java [servlet] 
But i can't find it.
my question is:
Is it the name of a servlet? if yes i can't find it in the project [a very huge one] i only find it in the web.xml file.

Thank you for your comments, answers and ideas.

Comment: the class name of the servlet is in the accompanying `<servlet-class>` element.

Comment: @ wero  thank you for your answer you mean   `<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>` You mean **DispatcherServlet** is my servlet ?? i should look inside **DispatcherServlet** ??

Comment: do you have org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet on your classpath? And if you give more line from web.xml, we could help faster.

Comment: @Hopeful yes this is your servlet. It is from Spring Framework, the latest version is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java

Comment: @Yusuf K yes yes, i have org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet on my xml.web `<servlet>
  <servlet-name>siterefServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>CoLo</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config/spring-mvc-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>`

Comment: @Hopeful Please give more detail about exception trace. Give more lines from servler.log about NullPointer exception.

Comment: @Hopeful And given web.xml have not enough details.

Comment: @Yusuf K ` 2016-03-21 12:02:46,217 ERROR ...
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders$ValuesEnumerator.nextElement(MimeHeaders.java:172) [jbossweb..]
at com.orange.siteref.rest.api.SiteApi.geographicSitesV1(SiteApi.java:92) [classes:] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]`

Comment: @Hopeful Please Edit your question instead posting as comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>YourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.servlets.YourServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <servlet-name>YourServlet</servlet-name>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It should not throw an exception, at least you're not telling something else 
You could try it via annotations, delete your servlet element from the web.xml and add

```
@WebServlet(servletName="YourServlet", urlPatterns={"/*"})
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet{
     //....
}
```